# Determining the number of servers per farm needed

Tags: 2010, server-farm, architecture, topology, certification

I'm studying for the 668 and don't understand why I need 4 SP servers for these farms based on the requirements.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here what i understand:
Farm1 will host the Service Applications( only cross farm services i.e UPA, MMS). so 2 servers are ok for this farm.

Farm2: according the deployment requirement....No services Applications on the servers host WebPages for user & also farm should be up and running if one server fails.

we need two WFE for failover...We need 1 App server for the Central admin and other server for the search.

Farm 3: again 2 servers for WFE( as fail over), One App Server( Central Admin) and One Server for the OWA as requirement is open word document in Browser and edit it.

SO user content will be accessible even one wfe is down.

Comment: OWA is not mandatory as a Standalone server in 2010.

Comment: That,s true but requirement is no services app on the server which hosted user content...and that farm required on a functionality as well...that,s why I put it on dedicated server in farm

Comment: For Farm 2 is says Farm 1 will host search service so wouldn't that remove the need for another? Also, how do you separate CA from WebPages? I didn't even know that was an option.

Comment: Central Admin is also WebSite but not serving the end user content. Central Admin is more about controlling SharePoint....so Search need one box(As per my experience we configured it atleaset on 2 servers).